# How to stop screen flickering from multiple imbedded stream builders to firebase-firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am creating a questionnaire builder which person A can drag and drop question widgets. the sections rows and questions are all saved onto firebase so that Person B can recreate them on other pages and fill out the questionnaire . at the moment i have a widget for the form which has a stream builder which collects the data from its collection, that form is made up of 'sections' which is made up of 'rows' which is made up of 'questions' each section, row and question has its own stream builder connecting to firebase.

The issue I am encountering is that when you load another form, or edit a question, it forces the page to rebuild which forces the whole form to rebuild all the sections, rows and questions. (this is what is causing all the flickering)

my question is how would I be able to make the streams connect and be independent from the stream builders? I've seen some things about setting the stream in the initstate function but i havent seen any examples using firebase and i haven't been able to implement them.

I tried to save all the ids into fire base but you cant store arrays of arrays. (hence why im having to store them in multiple documents) here is my code:

```
class FormSection extends StatefulWidget {
  FormSection({super.key, required this.sectiondata, required this.formsizewidth, required this.formsizeheight});
  Map<String, dynamic> sectiondata;
    double formsizewidth;
  double formsizeheight;
  @override
  State<FormSection> createState() => _FormSectionState();
}

class _FormSectionState extends State<FormSection> {
  late double formsizewidth;
  late double formsizeheight;
  late Map<String, dynamic> sectiondata;
  
  @override

  void initState() {
    formsizewidth = widget.formsizewidth;
    formsizeheight = widget.formsizeheight;
    sectiondata = widget.sectiondata;
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    List<Widget> rows = List<String>.from(sectiondata['rows']).mapIndexed((currentValue, index) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('rows').doc(currentValue).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              Map<String, dynamic> rowdata = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return FormRow(rowdata: rowdata, formsizeheight: formsizeheight, formsizewidth: formsizewidth,);
              }
            }
            return   Container(color: Colors.black,);
        }
      );
    },
  ).toList();

    return  Column(
      children: [
        Text(widget.sectiondata['title'], style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Satoshi',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          color: Colors.black,
          decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          fontSize: 20),),
        Column(
          children: rows,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FormRow extends StatefulWidget {
  FormRow({super.key, required this.rowdata, required this.formsizewidth, required this.formsizeheight});
  Map<String, dynamic> rowdata;
  double formsizewidth;
  double formsizeheight;
  @override
  State<FormRow> createState() => _FormRowState();
}

class _FormRowState extends State<FormRow> {
  late double formsizewidth;
  late double formsizeheight;
  late Map<String, dynamic> rowdata;
  @override

  void initState() {
    formsizewidth = widget.formsizewidth;
    formsizeheight = widget.formsizeheight;
    rowdata = widget.rowdata;

    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    List<Widget> questions = List<String>.from(rowdata['questions']).mapIndexed((currentValue, index) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('q&a').doc(currentValue).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              Map<String,dynamic> questiondata = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return FormQuestion(questiondata: questiondata, formsizeheight: formsizeheight, formsizewidth: formsizewidth,);
            }
          }
          return Container(color: Colors.black,);
        }
      );
    }).toList();

    return Row(
      children: questions
    );
  }
}

class FormQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  FormQuestion({super.key, required this.questiondata, required this.formsizewidth, required this.formsizeheight});
  Map<String, dynamic> questiondata;
  double formsizewidth;
  double formsizeheight;
  @override
  State<FormQuestion> createState() => _FormQuestionState();
}

class _FormQuestionState extends State<FormQuestion> {

  late double formsizewidth;
  late double formsizeheight;
  late Map<String, dynamic> questiondata;
  @override

  void initState() {
    formsizewidth = widget.formsizewidth;
    formsizeheight = widget.formsizeheight;
    questiondata = widget.questiondata;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
    return SizedBox(
      width: questiondata['answer'] != 'Multi Line' ?(formsizewidth / 100 * 25) - 1 : (formsizewidth / 100 * 99) - 1,
      height: (widget.formsizeheight / 100 * 25) - 1,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: questiondata['answer'] != 'Multi Line' ? 
(formsizewidth / 100 * 25) - 3 : (formsizewidth / 100 * 99) - 3  ,
            height: (`formsizeheight` / 100 * 25) - 2,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
              child: DisplayCorrectQuestionType(
                questiondata,
                formsizewidth,
                formsizeheight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```